# How bootloader or uboot load application to run

Tags: linux, assembly, ram, bootloader

Mini2440 or S3C2440 ARM9 Board has arm processor, when boot up from NOR flash, it can direct run from NOR flash, which loads a small boot loader called "super vivi", there is an option "Download and Run".

I tried compile a flash LED C program and relevant assembly code to load the C main function.

After compile, I created a bin file, load it to supervivi.

The link script is:

```
ENTRY(_start)
SECTIONS
{
   . = 0x30000000;
   /* code and constants */
   .text :{
      *(.text)
   }  
   . = ALIGN(32);
   .data :{
      *(.data)
   }
   . = ALIGN(32);
   .bss :{
      *(.bss)
   }
}
```

My question is how is memory are allocated, supervivi(bootloader) will be start from 0x0000000, my LED flash program starts from 0x30000000, is this correct?

supervivi will have some data or stack, where are they located?

If my link script change from ". = 0x30000000;" to ". = 0x0;", what will happen?

Can my application read NAND flash and copy it to RAM, say read from 0x60000, which is kernel stored place, and run kernel from RAM? If I can, where should the RAM position should I use?

Sorry too many questions, I guess they are related.